# REGEX no numbers or ( )

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that accepts everything except numbers and `(` & `)`.
I'm trying but I can't seem to get it.
Can anybody help me with this regex hell?

**Example**:

Hans Pedro (23123123) should be Hans Pedro. But the format can be different anytime.

Comment: Example: Hans Pedro (23123123) should be Hans Pedro. But the format can be different anytime.

Comment: Do you want the regex to reject the entire string or just extract Hand Pedro?

Comment: The example changes the question fundamentally.  Does `Hans Pedro (998abc00)` match? Is the `abc` accepted or rejected? Do the numbers _always_ appear inside the `()`?

Comment: If you have a string: "Jan d'es sol (3242) Erik"
After regex: Jan d'es sol  Erik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
/[^\(\)0-9]*/
```

this accepts all but the entered characters

Comment: It accepts anything that contains any number of characters not in this list. E.g., it matches `a12345`. It even matches `12345` …

Comment: I see this one works but when i do this: `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match("qwertyuiop (55A55) POI", @"[^\(\)0-9]+").Value` I get this as result: `qwertyuiop `

Comment: In your above example "qwertyuiop (55A55) POI", would the A in the ( ) be returned or ignored?

Answer (score 7):

You can use:

```
^[^0-9()]+$
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like so: `^[^\d()]+$` should do what you need. It will start from the beginning of the string (`^`) and match one or more characters which are not a digit (`\d`) or a bracket. It will keep doing this till it finds the end of the string (`$`).